# Make 2 elements float next to each other

Tags: html, css, contacts

I'm working on a simple contact form, but I'm having some issues making my content float next to each other.

```
<article>
<form action="contact.html">

          <label for="naam">Naam*:</label> 
          <input type="text"
                 id="naam"
                 required="required"/>

          <br/>

          <label for="voornaam">Voornaam*: </label>
          <input type="text"
                 id="voornaam" 
                 required="required"/>

          <br/>

          <label for="straat">Straat: </label>
          <input type="text"
                 id="straat" />

          <br/>

          /*Some code is left out */


          <label for="message">message*: </label>
          <textarea rows="4" 
                    cols="16"
                    required="required">
          </textarea> 

          <br/>

          <input type="submit"
              value="Verzenden"
              id="btnVerzenden" />

          </form>
</article>
```

And this is my current CSS

```
label 
{
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

How can I make my "Message" textarea float on the right side of the article while the rest is on the left side?

**UPDATE**

@PSCoder solved it!
This fiddle shows the solution - http://jsfiddle.net/8PvkV/

Comment: Well no. This is the result I get all the time. I want to have the side by side. Not on the next line (If you get what I mean)

Comment: You mean in 2 columns? other text boxes in one column and messages in another column?

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/8PvkV/ or http://jsfiddle.net/Hf47h/

Comment: Great! The first one is exactly what I trie to do. Thanks, you're awesome!

Comment: I don't think floats are a great idea for cross browser...I would still stick to inline-block

Answer (score 1):

Give your label : **display: inline-block;**

```
label {display: inline-block}
```

Here's a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/35Hyh/1/

Answer (score 0):

You want to either move the textarea element before the rest or float the form to the right.

Because of the order that you have entered the elements, the "Message" text box is cleared and then floated.